# Qt QDataStream: operator>> for quint16 - I didn't get it at all

Tags: c++, qt

I have such code:

```
    QByteArray portnoStr = "41034";
    quint16 portno;
    QDataStream stream(&portnoStr, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    stream >> portno;
    std::cout << "portno: " << portno << "\n";
```

And as completely unexpected it print

> portno: 13361

I look at the code of Qt (4x + 5x):

```
inline QDataStream &QDataStream::operator>>(quint16 &i)
{ return *this >> reinterpret_cast<qint16&>(i); }
```

At now I understand why it give me such result,

but I can not understand why QDataStream has such strange implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QDataStream` is not meant for converting data from one type to another in order to display text. [From the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#details):

> You can also use a data stream to read/write raw unencoded binary data. If you want a "parsing" input stream, see QTextStream.
>
> The QDataStream class implements the serialization of C++'s basic data types, like char, short, int, char *, etc. Serialization of more complex data is accomplished by breaking up the data into primitive units.
>
> A data stream cooperates closely with a QIODevice. A QIODevice represents an input/output medium one can read data from and write data to. The QFile class is an example of an I/O device.

You're using `cout` to print encoded binary data, which is interpreted as an integer. That data is meant for reading and writing to IO devices, not printing.

**Regarding `reinterpret_cast` to a `qint16`**: since `QDataStream` simply writes raw binary data, pretending an unsigned int is signed has no effect on the output to the data stream. This is just a cheap way of reusing code: the bits are ultimately written as bits, regardless of type. It's up to you to cast them back to the appropriate data type (`quint16`) when reading back out from the data stream.